# How does adaptive whitening work?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, online-resources

In the [Equivariant Adaptive Source Separation paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Equivariant-adaptive-source-separation-Cardoso-Laheld/ca9fc6bb80d7fd89055f46d716aa8b6e2e377a5e) I am wondering what the intermediate steps for eq. 23 on page 5 are? I am not sure where to even begin with this and haven't been able to find any information online.

Also, this paper introduced relative gradient to me (and I think introduced it in general) which seems like a really profound thing, but the author does not dwell on it at all which leaves me wondering. Is there anything that goes more into depth on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper, we have the following:
$$
\delta R_z = \mathcal{E}R_z+R_z\mathcal{E}^T \tag{21}
$$
and 
$$
K(R_z+\delta R_z) = K(R_z) + \mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\delta R_z\}+o(\delta R_z) \tag{22}
$$

If you replace (21) in (22), and use the fact that $R_z = R_z^T$ (symmetry), you get for what's inside the trace:
$$
(I-R_z^{-1})\delta R_z = (I-R_z^{-1})(\mathcal{E}R_z+R_z\mathcal{E}^T) = (I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z+ (I-R_z^{-1}) R_z^T\mathcal{E}^T) = (I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z+ (I-R_z^{-1})(\mathcal{E}R_z)^T.
$$
Using the [trace properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Properties), and $(I-R_z^{-1}) = (I-R_z^{-1})^T$ (thanks again to symmetry of $R_z$) you get
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z+ (I-R_z^{-1})(\mathcal{E}R_z)^T\}
 = \mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z\}+\mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})^T(\mathcal{E}R_z)^T\} = \mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z\}+\mathrm{Trace}\{(\mathcal{E}R_z)^T(I-R_z^{-1})^T\} = \mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z\}+\mathrm{Trace}\{((I-R_z^{-1})(\mathcal{E}R_z))^T\} = 2\mathrm{Trace}\{(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}R_z\} = \mathrm{Trace}\{2R_z(I-R_z^{-1})\mathcal{E}\}  = \mathrm{Trace}\{2(R_z-I)\mathcal{E}\} = \mathrm{Trace}\{2(R_z-I)^T\mathcal{E}\}
=<2(R_z-I)|\mathcal{E}>
\end{equation}

Identifying this with Eq. (14), we find
$$
\nabla\phi = 2(R_z-I) \tag{23}
$$

Comment: I noticed that the last term in eq. 14 is $o(\epsilon)$, but in eq. 22 it has the extra $R_z$ term inside it. Why is that?

Comment: Also why is the differential of function K eq. 22?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic, the tiny nudge $\delta R_z$ in Eq. (22) is expressed as a function of $\mathcal{E}$ (see Eq. (21)), so the general form is written using $\delta R_z$ but since we are replacing this by something function of $\mathcal{E}$ the end result is function of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: For the differential of function K, you just apply the differentiation rules on Eq. (19). You can find general formulas for derivatives of traces and determinants [here](www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic, you'll find that the derivative of the $Trace(R)$ wrt $R$ is $I$ and that the derivative of $\log \det (R)$ is $\frac{1}{\det (R)} \det (R) R^{-1}^T$ which gives as an end result $I - R^{-1}$ (symmetry: R^{-1}^T = R^{-1}). Then you plug this derivative (gradient wrt matrix) into the general expansion formula.